# Implementing typesafe heterogeneous container from Bloch's Effective Java in C++ (VS2010)

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio-2010

I would like to implement the typesafe heterogenous container discussed in Bloch's Effective Java in C++. The solution needs to compile in VS2010 but can use boost if necessary.

To be more specific I would like to implement a class that implements the following interface

```
abstract class IHeterogenousContainer{

    template <typename T> virtual add(const IKey<T>& key, const T& value) = 0;
    template <typename T> virtual T get(const IKey<T>& key) = 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? You might like to take a look at [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) for storing heterogeneous values.

Comment: Sorry I was hoping for advice on how to implement the interface above. 
Thanks, I'll take a look at Boost::Any.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Any does the job. This should basically do what the author shows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <typeindex>

#include <boost/any.hpp>

class heterogenous_map :
    std::map<std::type_index, boost::any>
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    void add(T&& value)
    {
        emplace(typeid(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type), std::forward<T>(value));
    }

    template <typename T>
    T      & get()       { return *boost::any_cast<T>(&at(typeid(T))); }
    template <typename T>
    T const& get() const { return *boost::any_cast<T>(&at(typeid(T))); }
};

int main()
{
    heterogenous_map map;
    map.add(6584);
    map.add<std::string>("Hi!");

    std::cout << "My favourite integer: " << map.get<int>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "My favourite string : " << map.get<std::string>() << std::endl;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f8ac64705e25dc3).

Comment: If I understand correctly the code above can only associate a single value with each type. If I add a

Comment: Thanks very much, I think I'll need to revise my C++ before I can understand everything above...

Comment: @daddycool: You're right. The code above indeed has that restriction, but it's in the `std::map<std::type_index ...` part. Maps cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: @daddycool You can use [`multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) instead. The code has to be modified though.

Comment: I need to associate keys of type IKey<T> with values of type T. I'm not sure how a multimap achieves this, am I missing something obvious?